# Kerberos: How does application server decrypt service ticket?

Tags: kerberos

From Kerberos architecture perspective, according to this graph during TGS_REP Client gets a service ticket which is encrypted using TGS session key. After that  Client takes the service ticket to Application Server to get a service.

I have seen that some document said that there is no interaction between TGS and application server. So my question is how Application Server decrypt the service ticket without TGS session key to verify the correctness of the service ticket?

[image: Kerberos architecture]

Answer (score 1):

The service ticket is encrypted with the server's longterm key known to the KDC.

Comment: Michael, if you know the details very well, can you please advice some implementation articles as well?

Comment: Does it mean if the client can get the service ticket, its prerequisite is the Application Server needs to register service on TGS and told the TGS its key first.

Comment: @cdhit. Yes, the service requires a service principal account known to the KDC. Please see this graphic: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(Informatik)#/media/File:Kerberos_german.svg At no point, the server talks to the KDC.